# Recyclerview Only Shows Data when I come back to the fragment but when fragment start for first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So I have an array list which is fetching data from the server and that data is displayed in recycler view.
Recycler view is only displaying data when I switch the activity and come back to the parent activity containing two fragments.

## `One of the two fragment class`

```
 public class ActiveJobsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ActiveJobsAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView emptyview;
    Button create;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    View v;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    String message, token;
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public ActiveJobsFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activejobsfragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.active_jobs_recycler);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        emptyview = v.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        if (prefs != null) {
            token = prefs.getString("token", "No token defined");
        }
        if (CommonObjects.modelList == null) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mAdapter = new ActiveJobsAdapter(getActivity(), CommonObjects.modelList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActiveJobCardDetailed.class);
                intent.putExtra("project_id",CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getProjectId());
                intent.putExtra("bname", CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getBusinsessName());
                intent.putExtra("lat", CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("long", CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getLongitude());
                intent.putExtra("date", CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getCreated() + "-" + CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getExpiry());
                intent.putExtra("amount", CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getAmount());
                intent.putExtra("address", CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("reimb", "68");
                intent.putExtra("shopper_name", CommonObjects.modelList.get(position).getActive().get(position).getAppliedUser());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        getQuestions();
        create = v.findViewById(R.id.create);
        create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), createjobs.class);
                onPause();
                startActivity(in);
                onResume();
            }

        });


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void getQuestions() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(CommonObjects.BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        getquestion Service = retrofit.create(getquestion.class);

        Call<Question> call = Service.post(token);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Question>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Question> call, Response<Question> response) {
                if (!response.body().getStatus()) {
                    message = response.body().getMessage();
                    showMessage(message);
                } else {
                    Question jsonResponse = response.body();
                    message = response.body().getMessage();
                    CommonObjects.q.setData(jsonResponse.getData());
                    CommonObjects.q.setMessage(message);
                    CommonObjects.q.setStatus(response.body().getStatus());
                    ArrayList<String> QidList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> QuestionList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (Datum data : jsonResponse.getData()) {
                        if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getQId())) &&
                                (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getQuestion()))) {
                            QidList.add(data.getQId());
                            QuestionList.add(data.getQuestion());
                        }

                    }
                    CommonObjects.Q_id = QidList.toArray(new String[QidList.size()]);
                    CommonObjects.Question = QuestionList.toArray(new String[QuestionList.size()]);
                    for (String s : CommonObjects.Q_id) {
                        Log.i("tag", s);
                    }
                    for (String s : CommonObjects.Question) {
                        Log.i("tag", s);
                    }
                    CommonObjects.Question = QuestionList.toArray(new String[QuestionList.size()]);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Question> call, Throwable t) {
                // handle execution failures like no internet connectivity
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ErrorEvent(-2, t.getMessage()));
            }
        });

    }

}
```

## The Home Class's `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar5);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(home.this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (prefs != null) {
        name = prefs.getString("name", "Anne Hataway");
        email = prefs.getString("email", "No email defined");
        businessname = prefs.getString("address", "No address defined");
        profile = prefs.getString("profile", String.valueOf(R.mipmap.icon_podcard_publisher));
        city = prefs.getString("city", "No city defined");
        token = prefs.getString("token", "No token defined");
        id = prefs.getString("id", "No id defined");
        location = prefs.getString("location", "No prefs defined");
        phone = prefs.getString("phone", "No name defined");
    }
    CommonObjects.token = token;
    CommonObjects.user_id = id;
    final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);

    mToogle.syncState();
    mToogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    ImageView imageViewMenu = findViewById(R.id.drawertoggle);

    loadImage(profile, imageViewMenu);
    imageViewMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    TextView tx = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.ed);
    tx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(home.this, EditAccount.class);
            onPause();
            startActivity(in);
            onResume();
        }
    });

    TextView userName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.clientname);
    userName.setText(name);
    getClient();
    CircularImageView mImageView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile);
    loadImage(profile, mImageView);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    tabView = findViewById(R.id.home_content);
    tabLayout = tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = tabView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    adapter = new DasboardPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //Add Fragment Adapter

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("token", token);
    ActiveJobsFragment fragobj = new ActiveJobsFragment();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    adapter.AddFragment(fragobj, "ActiveJobs");
    adapter.AddFragment(new HistoryFragment(), "History");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicator(R.drawable.icon_selector);

}
```

## The `Adapter` Class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar5);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(home.this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (prefs != null) {
        name = prefs.getString("name", "Anne Hataway");
        email = prefs.getString("email", "No email defined");
        businessname = prefs.getString("address", "No address defined");
        profile = prefs.getString("profile", String.valueOf(R.mipmap.icon_podcard_publisher));
        city = prefs.getString("city", "No city defined");
        token = prefs.getString("token", "No token defined");
        id = prefs.getString("id", "No id defined");
        location = prefs.getString("location", "No prefs defined");
        phone = prefs.getString("phone", "No name defined");
    }
    CommonObjects.token = token;
    CommonObjects.user_id = id;
    final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);

    mToogle.syncState();
    mToogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    ImageView imageViewMenu = findViewById(R.id.drawertoggle);

    loadImage(profile, imageViewMenu);
    imageViewMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    TextView tx = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.ed);
    tx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(home.this, EditAccount.class);
            onPause();
            startActivity(in);
            onResume();
        }
    });

    TextView userName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.clientname);
    userName.setText(name);
    getClient();
    CircularImageView mImageView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile);
    loadImage(profile, mImageView);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    tabView = findViewById(R.id.home_content);
    tabLayout = tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = tabView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    adapter = new DasboardPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //Add Fragment Adapter

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("token", token);
    ActiveJobsFragment fragobj = new ActiveJobsFragment();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    adapter.AddFragment(fragobj, "ActiveJobs");
    adapter.AddFragment(new HistoryFragment(), "History");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicator(R.drawable.icon_selector);

}
```

## `ActiveJobFragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/snow">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/active_jobs_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/soblue"
        android:text="No Data Available" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Want To create new project here?"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/create"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Create"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: what is your question ..could you elaborate this.I'm not getting your point

Comment: when the fragment is loaded for the first time the recycler view doesn't show any data. when I go into another activity and comes back to the main activity it is then when the  recycler view show data

Comment: `if (CommonObjects.modelList == null)` check this condition